# How to populate a matrix with blocks of different sizes?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have an 18x8 array. And blocks of different sizes A2-A7.

```
import numpy as np

A2 = np.tile(2, (8, 8))
A3 = np.tile(3, (4, 8))
A4 = np.tile(4, (4, 4))
A5 = np.tile(5, (2, 4))
A6 = np.tile(6, (2, 2))
A7 = np.tile(7, (1, 2))
main_list = np.arange(144).reshape((18, 8))
```

How is it possible to fill the main array with these blocks, if there is a possibility that several identical blocks may come to the input, but some may not come at all?

Location example:
[image]

Comment: There are 2 basic approaches.  1) make a large enough `zeros` array, and copy the blocks to their respective slots (with slice indexing).  2) concatenate blocks in multiple steps.  With an irregular mix like this you'll have to choose the most logical mix, building toward a vertical stack of 5 blocks.  `np.block` does the 2nd, but requires a more uniform mix of shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along those lines.

I did it in place, since I consider it better fit here, due to potential error handling you may want to consider.

```py
import numpy as np

A2 = np.tile(2, (8, 8))
A3 = np.tile(3, (4, 8))
A4 = np.tile(4, (4, 4))
A5 = np.tile(5, (2, 4))
A6 = np.tile(6, (2, 2))
A7 = np.tile(7, (1, 2))

#list to track blocks positions
hist_moves=[]
#Assuming "blocks" can only take positive numbers - let's make empty=-1
main_list = -np.ones(shape=(18, 8))
#block - block to be added
#position - top, left coordinates, to position block on the board
#board - board to put the block on
def put_block(block, position, board, hist):
    block_shape=np.array(block.shape)
    board_shape=np.array(board.shape)
    position=np.array(position)
    if(np.any(block_shape+position>board_shape)):
        #block is too big - doesn't fit the board
        return False
    elif(np.any(board[position[0]:position[0]+block.shape[0], position[1]:position[1]+block.shape[1]]!=-1)):
        #block overlaps with other blocks
        return False
    else:
        board[position[0]:position[0]+block.shape[0], position[1]:position[1]+block.shape[1]]=block
        hist.append((block[0,0], position.tolist()))
        return True

move_=put_block(A4, (0,0), main_list, hist_moves)
print(move_)

move_=put_block(A5, (0,4), main_list, hist_moves)
print(move_)

move_=put_block(A5, (2,4), main_list, hist_moves)
print(move_)

move_=put_block(A3, (5,4), main_list, hist_moves)
print(move_)

print(main_list)
print(hist_moves)
```

Outputs:

```py
True
True
True
False
[[ 4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]]
[(4, [0, 0]), (5, [0, 4]), (5, [2, 4])]
```

Comment: Thank you your answer helped) How can I find out the coordinates of the block?

Comment: I tweaked it a bit - I would record positions on inserting, since you can have single block on multiple positions- that would be the only way.